# How to write a calculator in Java with a character driven format?

Tags: java

character driven format of calculator in java
i get the error that the value of local variable `h` is not used. If someone could help me out please?

```
 public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double num1,sum;
    double num2;
    String h;
    System.out.println("|      MENU Calculator     |");
    System.out.println("| Options:                 |");
    System.out.println("|        a. Add            |");


    System.out.print("choose one option:");
    h=input.next();

    System.out.print("enter first num: ");
    num1 = input.nextDouble();

    System.out.print("enter second num: ");
    num2 = input.nextDouble();


    if (true)
        h="a";
    System.out.println("enter first num: " );
    num1=input.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("enter second num: " );
    num2=input.nextDouble();
    sum=num1+num2;
    System.out.println("sum: " +sum);
    }

        }
```

Comment: 1. it's surely a warning, not an error. 2. you're indeed never using `h`, you only assign values to it, and never read it.

Comment: What's your question? You don't use `h`? You don't, so the compiler is right!

Comment: Please read some tutorials and learn to understand error messages. "The value of `h` is not used". _You don't use `h` **anywhere** in the code you posted_

Answer (score 1):

Your code is almost right, but

instead of this line:

```
if (true)
        h="a"
```

use

```
if (h.equals("a"))
```

So:

```
public static void main (String [] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); 
    double num1,sum;
    double num2;
    String h;
    System.out.println("|      MENU Calculator     |");
    System.out.println("| Options:                 |");
    System.out.println("|        a. Add            |");


    System.out.println("choose one option:");
    h=input.next();

    //check if h equals a, then get the numbers  

    if (h.equals("a")){
       System.out.println("enter first num: " );
       num1=input.nextDouble();
       System.out.println("enter second num: " );
       num2=input.nextDouble();
       sum=num1+num2;
       System.out.println("sum: " +sum);
    }

}
```